# Is there an alternative to toFixed() in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to force a var to 2 decimal places, unfortunatly formatting the cell in sheets only works when the number is not part of a larger string so I need the value to be exact. Example below:

```
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"ERROR TEST", functionName:"errorTest"}];   
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('RUN', submenu);  
}

function errorTest(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var num = ss.getRange("A1").getValues(); //gets number 22.34567 out of A1
  var n = num.toFixed(2);
  var text = "Price of your item: £" + n;
  ss.getRange("B1").setValue(text);
}
```

The problem is this results in the error "TypeError: Cannot find function toFixed in object 22.34567."

- Is there an alternative to this that will remove/ pad a number to 2
  decimal places?
- If not does anyone know how to make a version of toFixed() so I can
  create it in scripts myself?

Thank you very much.

Comment: use `range.setNumberFormat("£0.00");` on your cells

Comment: Search for a "polyfill" of (missing feature)

Comment: toFixed works fine on Apps Script. Please add a [mcve] showing how you tried to use it and including the textual error message.

Comment: @Rubén, hopefully this is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the getValues() function which returns a two-dimensional array of objects/values.

[image]

JavaScript / Google Apps Script is good at changing between types but it won't recognise your variable num as a number, it sees it as a two-dimensional array of numbers.

If you call getValue() then you get a single object and Google Apps Script can treat it as a number allowing you to call the toFixed() function:

```
function errorTest(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var num = ss.getRange("A1").getValue(); //gets number 22.34567 out of A1
  var n = num.toFixed(2);
  var text = "Price of your item: £" + n;
  ss.getRange("B1").setValue(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you hero!